# Is there any dask method for string indexer

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I am doing this in pandas and it is giving me my desired output but how can i implement this using dask library.

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = pd.read_csv("newdata.csv")
df["Index"] = df["DAY_OF_WEEK"].str.index("day")
print(df)
```

Comment: without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is difficult to assist you

Comment: I have a column named "DAY_OF_WEEK" in my dataset and I want a new column in which shows the count of remaining word but not my sub-string. For example if string is "Monday" and my sub-string is "day" so the new column shows 3 or if is thursday and sub-string is "day" so it will show 4

Comment: @Muhammad please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve) as requested above.